# How to use regex in javascript to match a string with double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am very new to regex and I'm not sure how to pluck a piece of test from a very large string using regex.

suppose the string is this:
*FYI: This string would be generated dynamically pulling different elements from the database and the dom. I don't have much control on how it gets created.*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas architecto dicta amet cumque, atque, labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis. `<span itemprop="itemNum">56789</span>` labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis.

I need to get the text inside the span that has an itemprop labeled itemNum.

I tried this but it did not work for me:

```
/\b(itemprop=\"sku\"")\b/g
```

Ultimately I would have only 56789 in a variable.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: parsing html with a reg exp is not the best thing to do.

Comment: Why not just get innerHtml of the span element?

Comment: Because the string is not html per say. it is inside an object that gets created dynamically

Comment: @epascarello any ideas how to avoid that? As I mentioned above this complete string which contains html in it gets created dynamically

Comment: Can you get the html from that object? And is it just 1 span?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am not following your question. You mean targeting it using querySelector?

Comment: I am sorry, yes that is what I mean.

Comment: I don't think I can, and please correct me if I'm wrong, because the html is not in the dom. It is inside an object.

Comment: If it is inside an object, is there a property to access the html? Then you could use a DOMParser.

Comment: Mathias suggested that below. would DOMParser affect the real DOM in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to reach the goal of getting the value if you don't necessarily have to use regex would be to use DOMParser to first parse the string, then get the element using e.g `querySelect`:

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas architecto dicta amet cumque, atque, labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis. <span itemprop="itemNum">56789</span> labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis.';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
console.log(doc.querySelector('span[itemprop="itemNum"]').innerHTML)
```

Comment: Mathias would this affect the real DOM in any way? I am not familiar with DOMParser.

Comment: @Sergio It does not affect the "real DOM" in any way, it essentially creates a new DOM (document) in memory that you can use however you want

Comment: sweet! I will give this a go.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210948/3999647 just updated the regex and input

```js
function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
  index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
  var matches = [];
  var match;
  while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[index]);
  }
  return matches;
}


// Example :
var myString = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas architecto dicta amet cumque, atque, labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis. <span itemprop="itemNum">56789</span> labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis.';
var myRegEx = /(<span itemprop="\w+">)(\d+)(<\/span>)/g;

// Get an array containing the first capturing group for every match
var matches = getMatches(myString, myRegEx, 2);

// Log results
document.write(matches.length + ' matches found: ' + JSON.stringify(matches))
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

One probable solution.

```js
let str = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas architecto dicta amet cumque, atque, labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis. <span itemprop="itemNum">56789</span> labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis.`

let op = str.match(/<[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>/g).map(e=>e.replace(/.*?>(.*)<.*/, "$1"))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regex lookbehind for `itemprop="itemNum">` and lookahead for `</` then just capture whatever is between.

```js
const data = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas architecto dicta amet cumque, atque, labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis. <span itemprop="itemNum">56789</span> labore eos nobis earum fuga tempore officiis excepturi rerum placeat. Perferendis, earum officiis veniam dicta eius aliquid, similique porro quam necessitatibus nobis velit debitis.'

const res = data
.match(/(?<=itemprop\="itemNum"\>).+(?=\<\/)/)
//returns an array... get first value
.shift();

console.log(res);
```